# Use input() with ipywidgets.interact_manual

Tags: python, widget

Hello I have a widget where a user gives a couple variables and then a function is run when they click a button. Inside of this function, I would like there to be another user input. However when I do this it leads to an end of file error. This is being run in a jupyter notebook.

```
from ipywidgets import interact_manual
actions = ['action1', 'action2']

def myfunc(action, inputvar, alsoinput):
    #do_stuff
    do_more_stuff = input('Are you sure you want to continue?')
    if do_more_stuff == 'y':
        #do more stuff
    return

im = interact_manual(myfunc, action=actions, inputvar='abc', alsoinput='cdf')
im.widget.children[0].description = "inputvar"
im.widget.children[1].description = "alsoinput"
im.widget.children[2].description = "Perform Action"
im.widget.children[2].style.button_color = "orange"
```

I never get an option to input anything, I just get the error. How can I use input() inside of this widget without getting the EOFError?

Comment: don't use `continue` as a variable name. `continue` is a python keyword

Comment: also post the full error message you are getting

Comment: `input()` is meant to run in a console and I don't think it is compatible with running in ipywidgets in the manner you've tried. It may help to think of them as different tech, `input()` comes from when Python was just on the command line and IPython, IPython Notebook, and Jupyter didn't exist. Ipywidgets is for modern Jupyter. You basically want to stick with ipywidgets methods for collecting information from the user when using ipywidgets.